# sql server import wizard doesnot copy keys

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I want to import/copy Microsoft Access Database in SQL Server. This what I have tried.

```
Created a database using SQL Server Management Studio.
Then right click on this new database and tasks -> import wizard.
on first screen selected the type as Access and selected the file .mdb
Then selected SQL Server as destination database.
and selected the tables which I want to copy.
I also checked the identity enable to true.


The problem is it copied all the table but the keys are not copied....
```

Can any one please help. I am using sql server 2008.

thanks.